# How to search in an array that is in a json?

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to make a query to a json, the problem is when the search is performed in an array, if it is a property of the json that is not an array, it performs the search correctly, I want to be able to do it with 'where' only.

I have this:

```
$query->where('json_schema->lastYear->[0]->rate', '=', 100);
```

but it can't find it and if I do this:

```
$query->where('json_schema->name', '=', 'Test');
```

effectively it returns the record with `name` 'Test' but when looking in the array is where it does not do it

I don't want to use `whereJsonContains`

my json_schema:

```
{
  "name": 'Test',
  "lastYear": [
    {
     "rate":100,
     "premium":200
    },
    {
     "rate":300,
     "premium":400
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
$jsonValue = 'json_schema->lastYear->"$[*].rate"';
$result = $query->where($jsonValue,"=","100");
```

when performing `toSql()` I receive:

```
select * from `iquote` where json_unquote(json_extract(`json_schema`, '$."lossExperience"."rateChange"."generalLiability"."lastYear".""$[*].rate""')) = ?
```

Comment: Do you want to loop throw json

Comment: Do you mean you have mysql database with json type field? Add sample of your data pls

Comment: Quite so, I already edit my question and add it